# Google Maps JS API - Google My Maps tools

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a project where an user could draw on a google map a polyline, polygon, walking, driving an cycling route. 
All of those tools are available in Google My Maps app ([link](https://www.google.com/maps/d/))

Here is a picture:

[image]

On google Maps API documentation I found library called Drawing tools ([link to sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools)), but this is not what I am looking for. You can add to parameter `drawingModes` polyline and polygon, but there is no options for drawing a route.

Another picture:

[image]

So my questions are:

1. Is there a code or library or anything for tools from Google My Maps app (if there is, it could save me a lot of time - I need exactly what there is) **(yes/no) (if yes, where? Ignore other two questions)**
2. If not, are tools from My Maps (at least polyline and polygon) builded from library Drawing tools? **(yes/no)**
3. If yes, how can I add functionality to add routes? **(please provide a simple sample or hint how to add one of the routes driving/cycling/walking)**

Comment: This question is too broad. I think you should ask more specific questions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I really don't see how this question(s) are to broad. I clarified in bold what I meant. First two questions are simple yes/no, last one is just a request for a sample/link/documentation - anything to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to address your question

1. Google MyMaps and Google Maps JavaScript API are different products managed by different teams at Google. I'm not aware about any third party library or tool that allows to use MyMaps functionality via Google Maps JavaScript API.
2. MyMaps tools are not related to drawing library of Google Maps JavaScript API as I mentioned before.
3. I can see the following [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2953) in the public issue tracker regarding the ability to access Google MyMaps via Google Maps JavaScript API. However, it doesn't look like the API team has set a high priority on this task.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So there is no way to imitate an "Add a walking route" (as in MyMaps) functionality with Google Maps JavaScript API?